# i2c read requires return key

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, i2c

When I try to read data out my i2c-bus, i need to press RETURN to execute the read. I dont want it to do that automatically.

Also it does not read data but that might a problem of the i2c slave at the other end.

I dont know why it wants to have this keypress..

```
char recievedbyte[1];
printf("rB 0\n");
int er = read(I2C_BUS, recievedbyte, 1);
printf("rB 1\n");
```

I would expect that it does read the bus automatically at the read()-call. Actually, I need to press RETURN between `printf("rB 0\n");` and `printf("rB 1\n");`. when i do a read() with for example a textfile everything works fine...

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show more code. How do you open your i2c-bus? What is `I2C_BUS`? What value `er` do you get? What is in `recievedbyte` after the `read()`? Maybe you are not reading from the i2c-bus as expected, but from `stdin` instead.

Comment: I heve not heard about i2c with the keyboard attached :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to open() the I2C_BUS.
Due to that I2C_BUS was 0 (zero) and it read lines from stdin (thats why the ENTER key was needed.)